# Magento error when I try to add special price from admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

The error I get is:
Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice

This is a local copy of magento but I would not want to have to recreate the entire thing on the live site..any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The above solution didn't work in my case as I didn't develop any module therefore couldn't find any file named "specialprice" in the above mentioned path.

I have installed a module and it changed the "specialprice" backend path in the database to `catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice`

Here is the solution if you stuck in the same problem like me:

Run the DB query to check the value of specialprice attribute i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM `<database-name>`.`eav_attribute`
WHERE (
`attribute_id` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `entity_type_id` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `attribute_code` LIKE '%special_special_price%'
OR `attribute_model` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `backend_model` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `backend_type` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `backend_table` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `frontend_model` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `frontend_input` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `frontend_label` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `frontend_class` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `source_model` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `is_required` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `is_user_defined` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `default_value` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `is_unique` LIKE '%special_price%'
OR `note` LIKE '%special_price%'
);
```

**NOTE:** Replace `<database-name>` with your magento DB.

You will find three rows in the database. Navigate to the column named as "Backend_model" and then you will see one of the entry written as

`catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice`

So, change the above entry to

`catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate`

Save the database and then refresh the page on the magento frontend/backend (create and save a new product).

I hope everything is working fine. Good Luck!

Cheers,
Naveed.

PS: Thanks to all who helps others to learn.

Answer (score 6):

Open phpMyadmin

From your magento db

select the `eav_attribute` table

where the row which has the `backend_model` of:

'catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice'

Try this in the SQL tab in phpMyadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM `magentodbname`.`eav_attribute` WHERE `backend_model` = 'catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice'
```

Change the backend model to:

'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime'

Comment: Its working in my case with these steps. Upvote for the same. Can you explain me reason why this causing this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

While the other answers give workarounds (Replace backend model `catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice` with `catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate` in the `eav_attribute` table), nobody explained yet, why this happened.

The backend model `catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice` was introduced in Magento 1.9, so this error occurs when you run Magento 1.8 or older on a database that already has been updated to 1.9.

Probably you updated Magento and then reverted the code back to the previous version. Unfortunately at this point the update scripts for the database already ran and there is no rollback mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The backend model in defautl Magento is

`catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate`

located at

**app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Startdate.php**

If you are working with your custom module and the backend model specified is

```
catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice
```

then you need to create path something like this

**\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Startdate\Specialprice.php**

Change the **local/community** path as required.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below query :

```
UPDATE eav_attribute 
    SET backend_model = 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime' 
    WHERE backend_model = 'catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice';
```

Comment: Can you explain in your answer what this query does? The more detailed answer, the better ;)